# .Net Managed Control in IE11 doesn't work after anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, .net-framework-version

We have a control that is implemented in .Net 2.0 that is hosted on a webpage. Before the anniversary update it worked if we added the EnableIEHosting key to the registry but after the anniversary update the key have have been deleted from the registry. It still doesn't work even if we add EnableIEHosting to registry again.
To get it to work we need to have the url in trusted sites, and add fulltrust permissions in caspol.

This is how we embed it on the page:

We have noticed that it doesn't download the dlls any longer. So it seems that IE is blocking it somehow.

Have someone else experienced this problem and do anyone of you know about a solution?

Comment: I've seen the same issue. Contacted Microsoft, and they say they are aware of it, no ETA on a fix. Makes me wonder if it wasn't a deliberate change to make enterprises relying on IE 11 move on to something else.

Comment: Also, your question seems to be missing your code (I assume an object tag).

Answer (score 1):

With the same problem for 2 months, I've finally found a solution!

It seems that IEHosting is disabled when using document compatibility mode higher than 8 (which works flawessly in IE11 in previous Windows versions, WIndows 10 1511 included)

So you can:
- enforce IE8 document compatibility mode (but for all users) using X-UA-Compatible header or meta tag with "IE=8" content (i was using "IE=Edge" mode)
- or you can deploy EnterpriseMode on the Windows 10 1607 computers and specify IE8Enterprise for your website (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/turn-on-enterprise-mode-and-use-a-site-list)